# How do I create a view of content that contains a field collection field with multiple items?

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type (meeting) that contains a field collection (presentation). I'm trying to create a view using views_datasource (XML format) that lists the presentations in each meeting like this:

> - meeting1-field1
> - meeting1-field2
> - meeting1-presentations-field
>
>   - presentation1
>
>     - presentation1-field1
>     - presentation1-field2
>   - presentation2
>
>     - presentation2-field1
>     - presentation2-field2
> - meeting1-field4 etc..

and so on for each meeting node in the view.

I have setup a relationship on the field collection field, but I am unable to get the grouping to work correctly.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: checkout [Field Collection Views](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) maybe its useful for your situation.

Comment: This module is for swapping a views collection display with a view - it doesn't appear to help me.